# My settings app vanished

Tags: 22.04

Like... the in-built app you use in Ubuntu to change system settings. It's... gone. What?

Normally it should show up in this menu at the top right of the screen. I also can't find it by searching for "settings" in the launcher. IIRC the app is called "gnome-settings", and running that in a terminal does nothing either.

A reboot has not fixed the issue.

Ubuntu 22.04.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app is actually called `gnome-control-center`:

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

No idea how it got uninstalled. After installing it, you may find you need to restart the shell (Alt+F2, type "r" and hit enter). If this is inconvenient, you can just run `gnome-control-center` from a terminal.